# Layering Qt Windows with buildroot KMS/DRM

Tags: qt, buildroot, xorg

My project uses buildroot on a rockchip rk3288 processor (Tinkerboard). My project uses Qt QML with Qt version 5.9.1. I am using the libmali--gbm.so library, since provides me with eglfs_kms for my Qt app. I have used eglfs on an older framebuffer kernel on iMX6 devices, and its fast from bootup, simple, and doesnt depend on weston like wayland does.

I would like to layer two Qt QML windows, where the bottom layer is video, and the top layer is a GUI. Like this:

```
__________________________
|              ___________|_______________
|              |                          |
|  video       |                          |
|  layer       |                          |
|              |    ui  layer             |
|              |                          |
|______________|                          |
               |__________________________|
```

The UI layer will have a transparent backround, so the video layer can be seen beneath. On my last project (iMX6) used an older kernel, and had framebuffers to do this.

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB=/dev/fb0 QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs ./bottomWindow & 
QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB=/dev/fb1 QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs ./topWindow &
```

topWindow is basically an ApplicationWindow where the background is transparent:

```
// main.qml
ApplicationWindow 
{
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.QWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 720

    color: "transparent" 

    Text
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello" 
    }
}
```

The **reason** I want separate Windows is because I need to take screenshots & videorecordings of the MyVideoApp that has transformations in the QML. I cannot do this if the video resides in a QML surface inside MyUIApp. On my iMX platform I simply scraped the framebuffer (/dev/fb0).

My new project does not use framebuffers, it uses the KMS/DRM platform. This is okay, but I am not an expert in KMS/DRM. Most of my knowledge comes from https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/brezillon-drm-kms.pdf . I know that the DRM has a base framebuffer, and kms overlay planes. According to the Qt documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html it is possible to allocate the qt window to a KMS plane, but the variables I am attempting are not working:

```
# export QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.egl*=true
# ./bottomWindow &
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys: ("eglfs_emu", "eglfs_kms_egldevice", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys (sorted): ("eglfs_kms", "eglfs_emu", "eglfs_kms_egldevice", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Trying to load device EGL integration "eglfs_kms" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: New DRM/KMS via GBM integration created
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Using EGL device integration "eglfs_kms" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: platformInit: Opening DRM device
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Found the following video devices: ("/dev/dri/card0")
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Using "/dev/dri/card0" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Using backend-provided DRM device /dev/dri/card0
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating GBM device for file descriptor 5 obtained from "/dev/dri/card0" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: "DSI1" mode count: 1
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: mode 0 720 x 1280 @ 61 hz
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Selected mode 0 : 720 x 1280 @ 61 hz for output "DSI1" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Physical size is QSizeF(0, 0) mm for output "DSI1" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating new global GBM mouse cursor
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Initializing cursor atlas from ":/cursor.json" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Sorted screen list: QVector(OrderedScreen(QPlatformScreen=0x177e568 ("DSI1") : 2147483647 / QPoint(0,0) / primary: false))
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Adding QPlatformScreen 0x177e568 ( "DSI1" ) to QPA with geometry QRect(0,0 720x1280) and isPrimary= false
qt.qpa.input: X-less xkbcommon not available, not performing key mapping
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating window for screen "DSI1" 
eglfs >> createSurface GBM_FORMAT_ARGB8888
eglfs >> sucess to create KMS FB!


# QT_QPA_EGLFS_LAYER_INDEX=1 ./topWindow 
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys: ("eglfs_emu", "eglfs_kms_egldevice", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys (sorted): ("eglfs_kms", "eglfs_emu", "eglfs_kms_egldevice", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Trying to load device EGL integration "eglfs_kms" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: New DRM/KMS via GBM integration created
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Using EGL device integration "eglfs_kms" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: platformInit: Opening DRM device
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Found the following video devices: ("/dev/dri/card0")
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Using "/dev/dri/card0" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Using backend-provided DRM device /dev/dri/card0
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating GBM device for file descriptor 5 obtained from "/dev/dri/card0" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: "DSI1" mode count: 1
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: mode 0 720 x 1280 @ 61 hz
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Selected mode 0 : 720 x 1280 @ 61 hz for output "DSI1" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Physical size is QSizeF(0, 0) mm for output "DSI1" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating new global GBM mouse cursor
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Initializing cursor atlas from ":/cursor.json" 
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Sorted screen list: QVector(OrderedScreen(QPlatformScreen=0x14c1568 ("DSI1") : 2147483647 / QPoint(0,0) / primary: false))
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Adding QPlatformScreen 0x14c1568 ( "DSI1" ) to QPA with geometry QRect(0,0 720x1280) and isPrimary= false
qt.qpa.input: X-less xkbcommon not available, not performing key mapping
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating window for screen "DSI1" 
eglfs >> createSurface GBM_FORMAT_ARGB8888
eglfs >> sucess to create KMS FB!
```

As you can see the topWindow creates a **new framebuffer** and requests the DRM to switch to that new framebuffer. It does not use the KMS plane. I know for a fact that I have 4 kms planes :

```
GST_DEBUG="*:4" gst-launch videotestsrc ! kmssink 

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
...
INFO   GST_STATES gstbin.c:2506:gst_bin_element_set_state:<kmssink0> current NULL pending VOID_PENDING, desired next READY
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:367:log_drm_version:<kmssink0> DRM v1.0.0 [rockchip — RockChip Soc DRM — 20140818]
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:414:get_drm_caps:<kmssink0> prime import (✓) / prime export (✓) / async page flip (✓)
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format RG24
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format BG24
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format RG16
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format BG16
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format NV24
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format NA16
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:569:ensure_allowed_caps:<kmssink0> ignoring format NA24
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:686:gst_kms_sink_start:<kmssink0> connector id = 84 / crtc id = 74 / plane id = 75 <---------------plane id 75 being used
INFO      kmssink gstkmssink.c:708:gst_kms_sink_start:<kmssink0> display size: pixels = 720x1280 / millimeters = 0x0
INFO   GST_STATES gstelement.c:2676:gst_element_continue_state:<kmssink0> completed state change to READY
...
```

I have also tried setting both QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONNECTOR_INDEX=0 and QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_PLANE_INDEX=1 With the same result.

How do I get my qt app to launched on the kms plane ? Am I missing something in the Qt so that it doesn't create a new framebuffer?

Comment: Did you find some solution? I am in the same boat. But in my case one app uses eglfs and the other wayland. Both need to share the DRM using the QT EGLFS enviroment variables, but until now I could not come up with a working solution. Please give some insights if you have come across.

Comment: I did not. However, I contacted rockchip and they suggested to update the version of Qt. Rockchip now supports Qt 5.12 and 5.14, which have supposedly has the kms support. Unfortunately, at this stage, my project cannot update the entire sdk and dependencies, so I cannot try it.